# Conflict of Windows Drive Mapping in AD vs from Desktop

Tags: windows, active-directory, network-share

With Windows Server 2003, and XP clients what happens if the same network drive letter is mapped via 'Reconnect at login' from the desktop and the homeDirectory AD attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The AD attribute will take precedence over the local setting.  In other words, whatever path you set to mount via "Reconnect at login" will not be mounted, but the "Home Directory" path in AD will be.